# Validating date times (flutter/dart)

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

Has anyone gotten any meaningful use out of datetime.tryparse? I'm trying to accept date formats such as...

```
MM/dd/yyyy
MM-dd-yyyy
MM.dd.yyyy
```

it seems `DateTime.tryParse` always returns null for all of these formats. Is there a library or a more convenient way to accept date times of different formats.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DateTime.[try]parse` only parses a very distinct format, namely:

> a subset of ISO 8601 which includes the subset accepted by RFC 3339

To parse formats like `06/09/2019` use the `DateFormat` class from `package:intl`.

```
DateFormat.yMd().parse('06/09/2019'); // defaults to en_US, i.e. MM/dd/yyyy
```

This code:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  print(DateFormat.yMd().parse('06/09/2019'));
}
```

prints

> 2019-06-09 00:00:00.000

as expected

Comment: What happens if that date DOESN'T match that format? Is there a nice tryParse method?

Comment: It throws `FormatException ` and you catch and handle that.

Comment: so if I wanted to try to parse three separate formats in one function, call it validate, I wouldn't be able to really without three separate try catch blocks?

Comment: The `parse` should handle all those formats in one go (notice that I haven't specified the separator anywhere). You could also try `parseLoose` which is even more lenient.

Comment: hmmm...I added this exact code above, and I'm getting a format exception :/

Comment: It works for me. See the updated answer. Make sure that you are initializing `intl` for non-US-English locale if required.

Comment: You are going to need the 3 different formats, unfortunately: for example `DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy').parse('06-09-2019')`

Comment: Actually you had it perfectly right, I just needed to restart the app! Marking as answer now! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It is worse than you think:

```
DateTime.tryParse("2022-02-34")
DateTime (2022-03-06 00:00:00.000)
```

So for invalid input (format is correct but not the date) Dart knows better and retuns what it thinks is a valid date.

With invalid input there is no valid date

Comment: Try use parseLoose